# Need to access object jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

sorry, I'm new to jQuery and programming in general for that matter so apologies if my question is a little dumb..

I'm trying to write a quick and dirty form validation script in jQuery

I need to be able to access the properties in my 'settings' object from outside the scope of the 'init' method, I'm trying to get hold of it in another method I have called 'validate' I can't just pass the object as an argument in the validate method because I need to call my validate method later. Here's my script:

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {

            var settings = $.extend({
                bgColor: '#fff',
                textType: 'normal',
                textColor: '#666',
                errorMsgClass: 'errorMsg',
                requiredMsgClass: 'requiredMsg',

                ex: {
                    'email': /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/,
                    'message': /^[0-9a-zA-Z ."']+$/,
                    'name': /^[0-9a-zA-Z,\r\n ."']+$/,
                    'phone': /^[0-9 ]+$/,
                    'url': /^[0-9a-zA-Z,\r\n ."']+$/
                }
            }, options)

            return this.each(function() {
                var o = settings;
                var obj = $(this);
                var items = $(":input", obj);
                items.each(function() {

                    if (this.parentNode.className.substr(0, 8) == 'validate') {

                        $(this).bind({
                            focus: function() {
                                if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('id')) {
                                    $(this).val('');
                                }
                                methods.msgHide($(this), '.errorMsg')
                            },
                            blur: function() {

                                methods.validate($(this))

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            });

            return settings;
        },
        validate: function(el) {

            if (el.val() == '') {

                methods.is_required ? methods.msgShow(el, '.requiredMsg') : '';
                el.val(el.attr('id'))

            }
            else {
                //hide required msg
                methods.msgHide(el, '.requiredMsg');
                var last = methods.get_length(el);
                var reg = methods.getWrapper(el).attr('class').substr(9, last);
                if (!el.val().match(methods.init.ex[reg])) {
                    methods.msgShow(el, '.errorMsg')
                }
            }
        },
        get_length: function(el) {

            //see if it has the trailing asterix
            if (methods.is_required) {
                return el.closest('div').attr('class').length - 10;
            }
            else {
                return el.closest('div').attr('class').length - 9;
            }
        },
        is_required: function(el) {

            //see if it has the trailing asterix
            if (el.closest('div').attr('class').lastIndexOf('*') > -1) {
                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        },
        getWrapper: function(el) {

            return el.closest('div');

        },
        msgShow: function(el, message) {
            methods.getWrapper(el).children(message).css({
                display: "block"
            });
        },

        msgHide: function(el, message) {
            methods.getWrapper(el).children(message).css({
                display: "none"
            });
        },
    };

    $.fn.validateForm = function(method) {

        // Method calling logic
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.validateForm');
        }

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the settings object to whatever function needs it.

```
functionThatNeedsSettings(settings);
```